Does '後悔させる' sound natural?
In English, if someone provokes you, you can respond with "I'll make you regret that" as a threat. Can you translate by using the causative of 後悔する in Japanese and still sound natural?

お前を後悔させるよ

Or is there a different way to say it?

The use of the causative form itself is fine, but your suggestion seems funny to me. The last よ sounds oddly friendly...

Yes, the causative form of 後悔する is perfectly natural. It's seen very often in drama and anime. In fact, a Japanese speaker has asked the exact opposite of your question.「後悔させてやる」 is a pretty common phrase in fiction.
